# Change SharePoint Web Application port

Tags: port

We would like to change one of the web applications port from 8088 to 80.

Changing the port in IIS Binding does NOT seem to working. Should I be doing some additional steps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be changing the ports from within Central Admin, not IIS. You can do this from within the Alternate Access Mappings for the default, internal, and other port information.